# DPI changes in JAI.create... Why?

Tags: java, image-processing, resolution, dpi, jai

In the following code my source image has dpi of 600 but the result image will have dpi of 96, why?

```
RenderedOp source = JAI.create("fileload", "img/1.jpg");

FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("img/new1.jpg");
JAI.create("encode", source, outputStream, "JPEG", null);
JAI.create("filestore", source, "img/new1.jpg", "JPEG", null);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
ImageInputStream iis = ImageIO.createImageInputStream(new File("img/1.jpg"));
ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(new File("img/new1.jpg"));

Integer b = null;
while ((b = iis.read()) != -1) {
  ios.write(b);

}
```